# Error 406 Not Acceptable JSON

Tags: c#, json, api, artifactory

http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-CreateorReplaceRepositoryConfiguration

I am using the Create or Replace Repository Configuration call. However I am getting a 406 Error: Not Acceptable. Other PUT calls are working but do not return JSON. I believe JSON is the source of the error but have not been able to resolve or prove this.

I have added the code as below

```
RestClient Client = new RestClient(uriString);
RestRequest Request = new RestRequest(requestType);

Request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + credentials);
Request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

I've seen threads where adding the header to accept JSON resolves the error but this has not worked for me.

Comment: Can you add the JSON content you're trying to post ?

Comment: Your documentation states that the method produces `application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.search.ArtifactUsageResult+json`. Have you tried `Request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.search.ArtifactUsageResult+json");`?

Comment: From the docs looks like that method does not give a Json response. Try dropping the Accept header.

Comment: I did try without the accept but got the same error. Isn't the JSON in brackets what it returns?application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.search.ArtifactUsageResult+json is returned for a different call it looks like. I don't see a produce line for my method. http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactsNotDownloadedSince

Comment: Isn't the repository-config.json what it returns? 
{
repository-config.json
}

Comment: @gareth_bowles I am trying to PUT a simple url. No JSON. I am under the impression from the documentation that the PUT will return some JSON string.

Comment: I can run same json request with postman ,but in .net code take 406 error.I use application/json type both postman and c# .Is there any special configuration for jfrog call?

Answer (score 14):

A [406 HTTP status](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html) means that if a web server detects that the data it wants to return is not acceptable to the client, it returns a header containing the 406 error code.
The client can define the characteristics of the data it will accept back from the web server by using the accept headers.
In this case you declare the you would like to accept `application/json`:

```
Request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

however the REST API method you are invoking is returning `text/plain`.
You should change the code to accept text/plain:

```
Request.AddHeader("Accept", "text/plain");
```

Answer (score 1):

Wanted to add this for for future users stuck like me.  I was having the same issue and tried the request with Postman and saw that the Content-Type was "application/hal+json" I was trying it with application/json without luck.

So running a test in postman I was able to figure out what the server needed exactly.

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/hal+json"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same 406 Error: Not Acceptable when trying to get JSON on another site. In my case I could see correct JSON when typed url in my browser address field. But downloading it from the same url via my C# code have been producing 406 Error.
None of the answers in this topic solved my problem directly. But at least they pointed out to me that's the point is HTTP headers.

So I googled that page:
https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-http-headers-is-my-browser-sending
and added all browser headers to my code, and voila! It started to work.
In my case it was enough to fill some data in user-agent header.

Answer (score 0):

First, the `Accept` header states what the client is ready to get back, not what the client sends.
The header that states what the client sends is `Content-Type`.

Also, this method does not accept `application/json`. As clearly stated in the docs, it accepts one of the following:

- `application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.repositories.LocalRepositoryConfiguration+json`
- `application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.repositories.RemoteRepositoryConfiguration+json`
- `application/vnd.org.jfrog.artifactory.repositories.VirtualRepositoryConfiguration+json`